# Storing/querying binary sequences rdbms is it worth it?

Tags: performance, calendar, boolean, rdbms, bit-manipulation

**The use case:** a calendar of availability of hotel rooms.

**The regular approach:**

Have a table of availability with columns : (int) hotel_id, (date) date, (boolean) available

Which means 365 rows (if we consider one year of availability) per hotel indexed on dates

**The thing i'd like to try:**

Have a table of availability  with columns : (int) hotel_id, (bigint?) availability

1 row per hotel, query using bitwise operators to find/update availability :

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (availability & mask) = mask
```

**The question:**

Performance-wise is it worth it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To quote Knuth, "Premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of it) in programming."  Any vaguely modern database should be able to handle millions of rows in a table, so 365 rows / hotel / year will scale to quite a few hotels-years before being a problem.  The optimization you are suggesting imposes a significant maintenance cost as your queries become much harder to debug by hand.  It also makes it much harder to index your table, which is a major loss since most RDBMS systems are well equipped to take advantage of indexes, but not really well equipped to optimize bitmath in queries.

I would wait until you actually have a well indexed database with well written queries that you have isolated as the bottleneck in your system before looking into something like this, and honestly I would probably consider moving away from a traditional RDBMS (to something distributed, maybe MongoDB or Cassandra) before trying this scheme.

Comment: While I understand and completely agree with your statement regarding pre-optimization, 2000 hotels, 1+ offer per hotel, 365+ availability records per offer, 5+ websites/apps to serve...you might understand my worries. The no sql db approach is something i'd really be happy to study but i still don't see how it would help me here.
Thank you for your suggestions !

Comment: I still think you're better off going with good indexing over the bitmask solution.  2000 * 365 is still only about three quarters of a million rows, which really isn't all that big.  Do you have an existing system that is bottlenecked on the DB?  In general, I'd try Db/Server configuration, query optimization and indexing all before I went to the bit mask solution.  Even if you can keep track of the bit masks, you're leaving a major headache for whoever inherits that system, and someone will eventually use it wrong and get wrong data.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you get to > 10^7 of rows, your database engine should do just fine, so given your numbers, there's nothing wrong with the regular approach that you suggest. Even if and when you do get there, a stronger server (scale-up) and a good DBA can help you scale further.

In fact, the alternative that you suggest is far worse - you probably won't be able to index your availability column properly, which means that queries by date will be excruciatingly slow!

For example, you'll probably want to run a query like: SELECT hotel_id FROM hotel_avail WHERE avaliable = TRUE **AND avail_date = '2011-04-01'**; You need an index on the date column for that to run fast.

On top of that, rolling your own availability and mask scheme adds to the complexity of your system. It'll be harder to understand and maintain your code that does the "availability magic". Believe me, I've been there - it may look pretty initially, but after a while you can't remember yourself how those tricks of yours are supposed to work and it becomes a nightmare.

Finally, like @mark-tozzi mentioned, premature optimization is a bad idea. Despite all the trash talk that RDBMS's get lately, they usually perform much better than you expect and scale surprisingly well. They also usually to offer the most simple and reliable solution to your problem - 20+ years of development amounts to something. 
Where I work we use MS-SQL for a web application that handles billions of transactions per day, with some databases reaching hundreds of millions of rows and terrabytes of storage. We also use NoSQL (Riak, Couch, HBase) - but only where SQL can simply not go. This is not the case with your system.

Comment: In fact if i go the bitwise way, i wouldn't query by date but by mask ( i'll have to convert my dates to ints in code before). The query looks simple/short with biwise appraoch but less readable. The regular approach is far easier to understand but too verbose (it won't be that readble neither)...the problem is that i won't be querying by one date (you have to check all dates included in the stay period).
But may be the table definition in my regular approach is not efficient...?

Comment: What's your table definition then?

Comment: see  the question "(int) hotel_id, (date) date, (boolean) available"

Comment: @redben that table definition seems perfectly efficient - if you put an index on the date column, then it will efficiently support range queries (between date1 and date2), which should cover your need for checking all dates in a stay period.